# soapui 2.0.2 gives me NumberFormatException for even simplest expression

Tags: java, soapui, numberformatexception

I have a web service that I generate a sample request for, then replace all the ? with 0 for the simplest case.  It works fine.  Then I replace one of the values like this:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://interfaces.mypackage.foo.com">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <int:getCheckResults>
             <criteria>
               <startTm>
                 <time>${=0}</time>
               </startTm>
             </criteria>
          </int:getCheckResults>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

(The reason I'm trying this is, eventually, I want to pass readable dates like this when the interface expects a long ms value):

```
    <startTm>
      <time>${= new java.util.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm z").parse("01/01/2012 04:00 GMT"}</time>
    </startTm>
```

It always gives me the same answer instead of invoking the service - This used to work but I'm not sure what is different now, maybe it worked in an older version of SoapUI?

```
    <soapenv:Fault>
       <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>
       <faultstring>java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" Message being parsed:</faultstring>
    </soapenv:Fault>
```

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use context variables and a Groovy script.

In a Groovy script that runs before this SOAP request, add something like this (I didn't put your code in, but I imagine that you see what I mean):

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
Date today
String formattedDate
SimpleDateFormat formatter
Locale currentLocale
currentLocale = new Locale("en", "US")  
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", currentLocale)
today = new Date()
formattedDate = formatter.format(today)
log.info(formattedDate)
context.setProperty("formattedDate", formattedDate)
```

Then in the SOAP request put this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://interfaces.mypackage.foo.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:getCheckResults>
         <criteria>
           <startTm>
             <time>${formattedDate}</time>
           </startTm>
         </criteria>
      </int:getCheckResults>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thank you - I see what you mean, but since I'm trying to just run this from the SOAP UI, I don't have anyplace to run that goovy script beforehand.  The problem seems to be in SOAPUI itself, in the way it expands the ${= some java expression }  (or not).  I'm going to blow away 2.0.2 and try the latest 4.5 (win7 64bit) and see how that goes...

Comment: There is a Groovy Test Step that you can add into your Soap UI test.  Perhaps you are not seeing it because you haven't created a TestSuite > TestCase, etc.  If you run directly from the generated steps under the "I" icon, then you can't add in Groovy Test Steps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I blew away SOAPUI version 2.0.2 and installed the latest 4.5.0 and now it works as usual. God knows what was wrong.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Interesting.  I did not know you could do that.